# Simplified method to change the avatar picture?

Tags: support, profile-page

I just wanted to change my avatar picture into something nicer, but I did not succeed because this Gravatar thing is so annoying (I could not create an account/log in applying my usual login data, word press told me my user name is not available, etc ...).

Could physics SE do something to simplify the procedure? I mean such that one can just upload a picture from the local desktop to replace the default Gravatar picture that was dished out to a new user as he first registered to physics SE? 
It would be nice if there were a simplified alternative to using Gravatar in order to creat/change the avatar picture without need to register somewhere else ...

Comment: It seems to have been planned at one point, but it's been three years since :\ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/can-we-use-non-gravatar-avatars

Comment: once you create the gravatar site it does not matter the username you use as long as you have a valid email and you use the same email for gravatar as you do for stackexchange then you just enter your email address and it automatically applies the selected avatar to all sites that you use that specific email address

Comment: It's status-completed now, isn't it?

Comment: @Dimension10 yep it works now ... obviously :-). But [tag:status-completed] is a red tag, so only mods can attache it ...

Comment: @Dilaton: I meant that the mods should put the tag now...

Answer (score 3):

No, there's nothing we can do. The avatars are provided by Gravatar, which is a separate site that has no connection at all to Stack Exchange. Any problems you may have relating to changing your avatar, you'll have to take up with them.

Note that Gravatar is the simplified alternative to SE managing the profile pictures itself, not the other way around. All you need to do is provide your email address.